# Restar dos consultas sql en delphi

Tags: sql, select, delphi

Buenas tardes necesito restar el resultado de dos consultas sql que realizo por separado y luego almacenar el resultado en una variable. Es posible que sea de esta manera la forma de hacerlo?

```
if transaccionBanco.FieldByName('TIPO_DD').ASInteger = 1 then
    QryForDD.SQL.Text := Format('select sum(OUT_MONTO) as IMPORTE ' + 'from AFILIADO_ADH_COBRO_APORTES(:id_persona) ' + 'where out_anio = %d and out_mes = %d', [transaccionBanco.FieldByName('ANIO').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('MES').AsInteger])
else
    QryForDD.SQL.Text := Format('select saldo importe from  ' + 'CTACTE_RESUMEN(:id_persona, ' + '%d, %d, %d, %d, 1, 1) ' + 'where id_tipo_operacion = -2', [transaccionBanco.FieldByName('ANIO').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('MES').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('ANIO').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('MES').AsInteger]);
//query nueva
QryForDD1.SQL.Text := Format('select coalesce(saldo,0) importe from  ' + 'CTACTE_RESUMEN(:id_persona, ' + '%d, %d, %d, %d, 1, 1) ' + 'where id_tipo_operacion = -7', [transaccionBanco.FieldByName('ANIO').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('MES').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('ANIO').AsInteger, transaccionBanco.FieldByName('MES').AsInteger]);
//resta
DatasetDD.OpenWP([transaccionBanco.FieldByName('TIPO_DD').ASInteger]);
DatasetDD.First;
while not DatasetDD.Eof do
begin
    QryForDD.ParamByName('id_persona').Value := DatasetDD.FieldByName('PERSONA_ID').Value;
    QryForDD.ExecQuery;
    if (not QryForDD.FieldByName('IMPORTE').IsNull) and ((QryForDD.FieldByName('IMPORTE').value - QryForDD1.FieldByName('IMPORTE').value) > 0) then
    begin
        transaccionBancoItem.Append;
        TransaccionBancoItem.FieldByName('CBU_BLOQUE1').Value := DatasetDD.fieldByName('bloque1').Value;
        TransaccionBancoItem.FieldByName('CBU_BLOQUE2').Value := DatasetDD.fieldByName('bloque2').Value;
        TransaccionBancoItem.FieldByName('CODIGO_BANCO').Value := DatasetDD.fieldByName('CODIGO_BANCO').Value;
        TransaccionBancoItem.FieldByName('IDENTIFICADOR').Value := DatasetDD.fieldByName('IDENTIFICADOR').Value;
        TransaccionBancoItem.FieldByName('PERSONA_ID').Value := DatasetDD.FieldByName('PERSONA_ID').Value;
        TransaccionBancoItem.FieldByName('IMPORTE').Value := QryForDD.FieldByName('IMPORTE').Value;
        QryForDD.Close;
        transaccionBancoItem.Post;
    end;
    DatasetDD.Next;
end;
```

Comment: Que seria restar dos consultas? restar el resultado de las mismas? porque lo que estas haciendo ahi, pareceria ser que solo restas dos campos de tipo string...

Comment: Si, perdón, me mal exprese. El resultado de cada consulta es un numero (ejemplo: la primera consulta me devuelve 1200 y la segunda 1000, y necesito restar esos dos valores para luego hacer otras cosas con ese resultado).

Comment: o eso se haria con lo siguiente?
(QryForDD.FieldByName('IMPORTE').value - QryForDD1.FieldByName('IMPORTE').value)

Comment: No se que es QryForDD1 (no se que tipo de objeto es ni que contiene) pero podria ser asi.. en algun momento ejecutas esas querys? esto no lo podes hacer en la DB por algo en particular?

Comment: ahi te edito el codigo y lpo pongo completo

Comment: Tenes que hacer como pusiste en tu comentario..

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es hacerlo en el cliente cuando te lleguen los datos a tu programa Delphi y otra opción es **hacer el cálculo en el servidor**.
Si tienes 2 consultas que te devuelven un importe, por ejemplo estas 2 (similares en estructura a las que tú tienes):

```
Select importe from tabla1 where nombre='Pepe'
select * from Tabla2 where codigo=2
```

Dos consultas que te devuelven un campo Importe.

[image: Resultado de ejecutar las 2 consultas y lo que devuelve el IMPORTE en ambas]

Puedes ejecutar lo siguiente en el servidor (seguro que hay otras opciones) para realizar la suma allí y obtener un único importe.

```
SELECT SUM (IMPORTE) AS TOTAL from
(
select importe from (Select importe from tabla1 where nombre='Pepe') as T1
UNION
select importe from (select IMPORTE from Tabla2 where codigo=2) AS T2) 
AS TOTAL
```

El resultado de ejecutar esa `SELECT` será el siguiente:

Puedes ajustar tus consultas para seguir esa misma estructura. Una vez ejecutada sólo debes recoger el importe desde Delphi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]